# Case-insensitive regex in XSD

Tags: regex, xsd

Is there a better way to do the following?

```
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:pattern value="hulu|Hulu|netflix|Netflix"></xs:pattern>
</xs:restriction>
```

Basically I want a case-insensitive match on the word.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

XML Schema (XSD) does not provide a case-insensitive matching mode for its facet regular expressions.  You can simply match both cases explicitly:

```
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:pattern value="[Hh][Uu][Ll][Uu]"/>
    <xs:pattern value="[Nn][Ee][Tt][Ff][Ll][Ii][Xx]"/>
</xs:restriction>
```

Comment: True, there is no case-insensitivity flag, but there is alternation in [XML Schema Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/xml.html).

Comment: @stribizhev, I never said there wasn't alternation; I merely used an alternative form that is also supported and is arguably more readable.  You can quibble with which is more readable if you'd like, but the essence of the answer is that (1) there is no case-insensitive matching mode available and (2) you can match both cases explicitly instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could do [Hh]ulu|[Nn]etflix

Comment: Right, what if it's even more non-standard: HULU, NETFLIX, etc.

Comment: In that case you should find out if you can apply flags to your regex, in python you can match with an re.IGNORECASE flag in order to ignore case.